# How to rename context menu items in handsontable.js?

Tags: javascript, frontend, handsontable

I satisfy with copy option in contextmenu of hansontable but my users would like to see translated name for this item('копировать'). Is any simple way to rename a contextmenu item in handsontable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rename the items in your context menu, you need to customize it as described in the [documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/demo-context-menu.html#page-custom).

Following their example, you need to use the parameter 'name' of the "copy" item :

```
hot3.updateSettings({
  contextMenu: {
    items: {
      "copy": {name: 'копировать'},
    }
  }
})
```

You cand find an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wqeLyz/).